# Bootstrap Span breaking

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an issue with bootstrap spans.

My code:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span3" style="background-color: white">
                test
            </div>
            <div class="span3" style="background-color: white">
                test
            </div>
            <div class="span3" style="background-color: white">
                test
            </div>
            <div class="span3" style="background-color: white">
                test
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The issue is, that the last span is not in the same row while they all add up to span12.

[image: what it looks like]

Comment: It looks like you have modified either `.container` width or `[class*=span]` margin

Comment: If you are using Bootstrap 3, you need to use col-lg-3 instead of span3.